# Flutter - Geolocator package is not calling Geolocator.getCurrentPosition() more than once

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages, geolocator

As the title says, I'm not being able to call Geolocator.getCurrentPosition() more than once. I have logged the issue with the package team, but I'm wondering if it's something I'm doing wrong.

```
  Future getLocation() async {
    var currentLocation;
    try {
      currentLocation = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      currentLocation = null;
    }
    return currentLocation;
  }

  void getLocation1() async {
    var location = await getLocation();
    print(location);
    print("First");
  }

  void getLocation2() async {
    var location = await getLocation();
    print(location);
    print("Second");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation1();
    getLocation2();
  }
```

The console prints "Second" but not "First". When I remove the getLocation2() call, the console prints "First". They are not able to be called in the same frame, and I don't know why this changed. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why would you need an "old" location update?

Comment: I'm using them for different subscriptions in another file. Regardless, it doesn't get called twice and want to know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are experiencing this behavior on iOS or macOS. The reason is that Apple doesn't allow multiple active calls to the location stream. What happens is that the `getLocation2` method closes the active request currently running by the `getLocation1` call.

The easiest way to workaround this, is to return the same `Future` if the first request has not been finished yet:

```dart
  late Future<Position> _positionFuture;

  Future<Position> getLocation() async {
    if (_positionFuture != null && !_positionFuture!.isCompleted) {
      return _positionFuture;
    }

    _positionFuture = Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.medium,
      );
    return _positionFuture;
  }

  void getLocation1() async {
    var location = await getLocation();
    print(location);
    print("First");
  }

  void getLocation2() async {
    var location = await getLocation();
    print(location);
    print("Second");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getLocation1();
    getLocation2();
  }
```